# Regular Expression For Characters Like AA, BA, ......DD,FF

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can write a regular expression for a textbox that must contain AA, BA, BB, CB, CC, DC, DD, FF, ND. Can you help me for this?

Comment: `...where col like '%AA%' or col like '%BA%' or col like '%BB%'...`

Comment: Are you trying to do this at the SQL level, model level, or view level?

Comment: its not possible i guess.. because you are asking for a sequence of characters.. and regular expression is to validate a particular pattern

Comment: sorry @RowlandShaw. at the model level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
/(AA|BA|BB|CB|CC|DC|DD|FF|ND)/

But i Think its better to use a server-side validation for this.

Comment: thank u @Ixlang . how can i write regular expression for a textbox can't contain sql injection codes at model level (except AA.....FF)